# Как 1 раз вставить в строку1, другую строку2, после определенного набора символов?

Tags: php

```
$str2 = 'some html code';
$str1 = '<h1>H1</h1> <p> <!--Как сюда вставить str2?--> text</p> <p>text</p>';
//str2 нужно вставить после первого найденого набора символов <p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *нужно вставить после первого найденого набора символов*

Используйте preg_replace() с указанием количества производимых замен:

```
$str2 = 'some html code';
$str1 = '<h1>H1</h1> <p> text</p> <p>text</p>';

echo preg_replace('~(?<=<p>)~', $str2, $str1, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$str2 = 'some html code';
$str1 = '<h1>H1</h1> <p> <!--Как сюда вставить str2?--> text</p> <p>text</p>';

$subString = '<p>';

// находим позицию первого вхождения тега <p> в строке
$position = strpos($str1, $subString);

// делаем вставку в строку
echo substr_replace ($str1 , $str2 , $position + strlen($subString), 0);
```